# Xcode system clear and "expression result unused" error using C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, system

While attempting to code a Tic Tac Toe game in Xcode to practice C++, I'm running into all sorts of issues which I have mostly fixed but I'm still having trouble understanding why I'm getting the following errors and how to properly fix them/avoid them.

**Problem 1:**

I've linked the curses library but I still get this error:**conversion from string literal to 'char*' is deprecated**.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <term.h>
void ClearScreen()
{
if (!cur_term)
{
    int result;
    setupterm( NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, &result );
    if (result <= 0) return;
}
putp( tigetstr( "clear" ) );
}
```

**Problem 2:**
I keep getting an **Unused Entity Issue** (*Expression result unused*).
(gridBox is a 2-d array of type char and player is type char as well, both global variables.)

```
    if (gridBox[0,0] == gridBox[1,0] && gridBox[1,0] == gridBox[2,0]) {

    if (player == 'X') {
        return 'X';
    }
    if (player == 'O') {
        return 'O';
    }
}
```

**Problem 3:**
When I try changing the if statement in the last problem to...

```
    if (gridBox[0,0] == 'X' && gridBox[1,0] == 'X' && gridBox[2,0] == 'X') {
    return 'X';
}
```

I get this error:**Comparison between pointer and integer ('char*' and 'int')**.

This is driving me completely insane, please help.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Expressions such as `0,0` won't do what you expect them to do as array indexes. At least not for standard arrays. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, with complete variable declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is just that: implicit conversion from a string literal, such as `"clear"`, to a pointer to non-const char, `char*`, used to be allowed for historical reasons but has been deprecated because it's very unsafe.
   This can cause some issues when interfacing with C libraries or old code, but is usually easily worked around.

   Replace it with a non-const array:

   `char clear[] = "clear";
    putp(tigetstr(clear));`
2. Is caused by indexing the wrong way; a 2-D array is an array of arrays, and it is indexed like this:

   `gridBox[0][0]`

   The comma operator is used in some contexts if you want to evaluate two expressions in sequence and throw away the result of the first - `a, b` returns the value of `b`, so `gridBox[0,0]` is equivalent to `gridBox[0]`.
   It's quite rare in practice - so rare that compilers have started issuing warnings because it's almost never what you intend.
3. Since `gridBox` is an array of arrays of `char`, and since because of point 2) `gridBox[0,0]` is  equivalent to `gridBox[0]`, `gridBox[0]` is an array of char.
   You can't compare arrays with `==`. Instead, they are implicitly converted to pointers to the array's first element, which are then used for comparison.
   Thus, the left hand side is a `char*`, and the right hand side is promoted to an `int` for comparison purposes, and those two can't be compared.
   If you fix your indexing problem, this problem will disappear at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much man you really helped me understand what was going on behind the scenes! One last question unfortunately... after I made the changes to the **ClearScreen** function..it fixed the errors but it did not clear my screen. Can you please answer how I could go about fixing that?

Comment: @user3902496 Sorry, I have never worked with curses, but you should probably check the return value of `setupterm` for errors, and verify that `putp` is called.